# Does scrollintoview work when there is less content on the page and there is no page scroll on the web page because of less content

Tags: javascript, html, js-scrollintoview

Does scrollintoview work when the targeted element is within the page of less contents because of which page scroll does not appear on the web page

Issue is my scrollintoview functionality works fine and scroll smoothly to the targeted element when the targeted element is in the web page having scroll bar. But fails when the same targeted element is in the web page having less contents , because of which scroll bar of the web page won't appear, and my scrollintoview functionality to the targeted element is not working

Comment: Can you define "work" more clearly. What is it that you expect and aren't seeing? [This guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can help you flush out your question better so others can help you better.

Comment: Are you using, the alignToTop parameters? see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView